# Sprint-Boot Application does not end when using a HttpClient with sendAsync with a newFixedThreadPool

Tags: java, spring-boot, executorservice

When using a HttpClient (java.net.http.HttpClient) to do some GET requests I want to use a FixedThreadPool.

Therefore I wrote a spring-boot application with this method (for testing it):

```
public class AppStartupRunner implements ApplicationRunner {
  // ....
  private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

  @Override
  public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
  
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder().executor(executorService).build();
    //HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder().build();
  
    String url = "https://<url>";
    try {
      httpClient
        .sendAsync(HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(URI.create(url)).GET().build(), BodyHandlers.ofString())
        .thenApply(HttpResponse::body).get();
    } catch (
        Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    System.out.println("Out");
  }
  // ....
}
```

My problem is that when I run this application the http call gets done and I receive my data. I also already checked with the "isDone" method and it confirms that the request is completed. But the application does not end - I think the main thread does but there is still one (or more?) processes hanging/waiting.

When I am replacing the httpClient with the one which does not use my executorService then the application ends correclty.

One point: when I let the HttpClient use the executorService and at the end explicitly shutdown the executorServer (--> executorService.shutdown();) the application ends correctly, too. However I am not sure if this is the right solution, or just hiding a problem. Because the 10 Threads from the executorService are always running (whether the httpClient uses them or not), so I do not see what I would need to shutdown the executorService if it is used and otherwise I won't...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way is to call `executorService.shutdown()` after confirming all threads are done. Before `shutdown()` is called, the 10 threads would still be alive and waiting.

Bare in mind, after calling `executorService.shutdown()`, no more new threads can be added into the service, which in your case I think it is safe, as every time your application runs, a new `ExecutorService` is being built.

You can read further in documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

Comment: Hi Phil, alright thanks for the info. One question: Can you help me and explain why the programm exits normally in case the thread pool is not used?

Comment: When the threadpool is not used, there would not be waiting threads after all http calls are processed, hence the application can exit normally